# Fixing a TypeError when using pandas after replacing a string with a floating point number to eventually generate a bar graph of monthly total precip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and using pandas and I am needing help creating a bar graph after changing a string 'T' to 0.005 inches of rain in a daily precip column. Below is some sample csv data:

```
Date        HighT  Avgt   LowT   Precip
2017-01-01  46     35     24     T
2017-01-02  54     48     41     0
2017-01-03  54     45     34     0.33
2017-01-04  30     24     19     0.36
```

The csv file is daily weather data for the year 2017. I have daily precipitation amounts and replaced 'T' (which means trace amounts) with 0.005 using pandas. I converted the dates to use as my index from the csv file.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wt = pd.read_csv('CSV/2017-weather.csv')

wt['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(wt['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%y')
wt.index = wt['Date'] 
del wt['Date']

wt.loc[wt['Precip']=='T', ['Precip']] = 0.005
```

In attempt to plot the bar graph I first tried this:

```
wt.groupby(wt.index.month)['Precip'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

However, I keep getting a TypeError saying: "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly."

I then tried making the 'Precip' column its own data frame, converting it to all floating points, and then tried to make the bar graph again:

```
wt2 = wt[['Precip']]

wt2.astype(float)

wt2.groupby(wt2.index.month)['Precip'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

I still get the same error I mentioned above and I'm not sure how to fix the error at this point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind posting a few simplified rows of the csv or dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first row of data in the data you provide, you can see that the `Precip` value is `"T"`. As this isn't a number, it can't be converted to a `float`, so the `TypeError` is thrown.

Try removing that first row and your code should work.

Comment: As part of our assignment, we had to replace "T" (which means trace amounts) to a floating point number of 0.005. I used the code: wt.loc[wt['Precip']=='T', ['Precip']] = 0.005 to do so. I still get an error after converting the T to and the other values to floating points.